# JQuery - Find element that has a given number of siblings

Tags: javascript, jquery, find

I need to be able to search through each level of descendants of a JQuery object, and return any collections of siblings that may have a given number of members at that hierarchy level, starting with the objects most distant descendants, and working its way back up.

So given some HTML:

```
<div class="search-me">
  <div> <!-- DON'T FIND THIS -->
    <p>FIND ME</p>
    <p>FIND ME</p>
    <p>FIND ME</p>
  </div>
  <div> <!-- DON'T FIND THIS -->
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <div> <!-- DON'T FIND THIS -->
    <div>FIND ME</div>
    <div>FIND ME</div>
    <div>FIND ME</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need the following pseudo code, to return the items labelled 'FIND ME', and nothing else...

```
$('.search-me').findGroupWithSize(3);
```

Also, note that there are three div's containing the `<p>`, `<span>`, and `<div>` tags, which should **not** be returned. So it should return a collection of the **lowest** level set of elements, whose siblings total a given amount.

Comment: Are you trying to match elements where there are three total siblings within the parent element?

Comment: If someone wants to write out a solution to this, that's fine, but I bet you can figure it out. Try starting with jQuery's `.find()` - https://api.jquery.com/find/. See what you get back if you `console.log($('div').find('p')`...

Comment: @Jack_Hu What do you mean by "lowest level" at _"So it should return a collection of the lowest level set of elements, whose siblings total a given amount."_? That description is not clear and is a different question from original question. Have you read linked  help document at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45666962/jquery-find-element-that-has-a-given-number-of-siblings/45667167#comment78291872_45667088?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below example finds the groups of 3 from the HTML you posted.

```js
var siblingsGroupTarget = 3;
var foundIndex = 0;
var elementArray = [];

$(".search-me").find("*").each(function(index){
  // Conditions
  var hasChilds = $(this).children().length;
  var hasSiblings = $(this).siblings().length;
  var itsSiblings = $(this).siblings();
  var itsSiblingsHasChilds = itsSiblings.children().length;

  console.log( $(this)[0].tagName+": "+$(this).siblings().length );

  if( hasChilds == 0 && ( hasSiblings == siblingsGroupTarget-1 && itsSiblingsHasChilds == 0 ) ){
    elementArray.push( $(this) );
  }
});

elementArray.reverse();
for(i=0;i<elementArray.length;i++){
  foundIndex++;
  elementArray[i].addClass("FOUND").append(" I was found #"+foundIndex);
};
```

```css
.FOUND{
  border:3px solid red;
  width:12em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="search-me">
  <div> <!-- DON'T FIND THIS -->
    <p>FIND ME</p>
    <p>FIND ME</p>
    <p>FIND ME</p>
  </div>
  <div> <!-- DON'T FIND THIS -->
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <div> <!-- DON'T FIND THIS -->
    <div>FIND ME</div>
    <div>FIND ME</div>
    <div>FIND ME
      <ul> <!-- DON'T FIND THIS -->
        <li>FIND ME</li>
        <li>FIND ME</li>
        <li>FIND ME</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I get that, but the real use case could be many, many levels deep, which is why I stipulated it needs to work in reverse, from the greatest grandchild of the origin object, and work its way back to the origin. I'm not sure how I find the youngest grandchild of an object in jquery, to start recursively looping backwards...

Comment: I was pretty sure you would talk about many levels... But what is the real use case importance of the "backward" aspect ?

Comment: It's part of a search algorithm I'm working on... I guess what my question ultimately boils down to is, "How can I find the youngest possible descendent of a given element?". If I knew that, then it would be a lot easier.

Comment: @Jack_Hu What do you mean by "youngest possible descendant"? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It's closer, but the search needs to terminate once it's found it's first matching set (providing there aren't any more at the same level, but on a different branch, in which case they need to be returned too). So in this case, it would only match the `li` items, and that's it. Which is why it's important it starts furthest away, and works backwards.

Comment: Awesome stuff. Thanks a lot. :) Plenty for me to read, re-read, understand, forget, re-learn. Just awesome. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use selector `".search-me > *"` passed to `jQuery()` to get direct descendants of `.search-me` element, `.toArray()` to convert jQuery object to array, `Array.prototype.reverse()` to reverse the collection of elements, `.filter()` to check if the child elements `.length` is `N`, wrap array methods in `jQuery()` with selector `"> *"` to return child elements of matched elements

```js
const N = 3;

let res = $("> *", $(".search-me > *").toArray().reverse()
          .filter(function(el) {return $("> *", el).length === N}));

console.log(res);

res.css("color", "purple")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="search-me">
  <div> <!-- DON'T FIND THIS -->
    <p>FIND ME</p>
    <p>FIND ME</p>
    <p>FIND ME</p>
  </div>
  <div> <!-- DON'T FIND THIS -->
    <span>DON'T FIND ME</span>
    <span>DON'T FIND ME</span>
  </div>
  <div> <!-- DON'T FIND THIS -->
    <div>FIND ME</div>
    <div>FIND ME</div>
    <div>FIND ME</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have a link to get more information about the JQuery construct `$("> *", $(".search-me > *")`? Namely, the two argument constructor? I'm assuming that's what it is?

Comment: @Jack_Hu The first parameter is the selector string, the second parameter is the `context` against which the selector string should match, see [`jQuery()`](https://api.jquery.com),  [CSS Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

Comment: So would this code work, traversing down, say, 10 levels? Or is it again limited to 2 levels? I'm assuming that that's what the `$("> *", ".search-me > *"` is doing, looking at the children, in the context of the children, so effectively the grandchildren. It could be that the match I need is on descendent level 7/13 (7 out of 13), or 24/115, etc..

Comment: @Jack_Hu _"So would this code work, traversing down, say, 10 levels?"_ , _"It could be that the match I need is on descendent level 7/13 (7 out of 13), or 24/115, etc.."_ That is an entirely different question from original question